# Photos.app Library displays no photos, despite all photos being downloaded

Tags: macos, icloud, photos, photos.app

Photos is not displaying any photos in the Library.
[image]

Context:

- Located on my main drive, library size is ~80GB, and 1TB of free space.
- Photos are synced with iCloud
- iCloud is set to "Download Originals to this Mac"
- The other tabs *do* show photos, e.g. "Memories" is loading normally. *However*, when right clicking and selecting "Show in All Photos" - it returns to the blank Library screen.
- All photos are in the .photoslibrary (even new ones).
- No errors can be found (in UI or logs)
- Other devices (e.g. iPhone) are behaving normally

What I've tried:

- Restarting
- Toggle iCloud
- Deleting Photos Library.photoslibrary and making a fresh one
- Running Repair Library

Currently running macOS 12.3.1 Monterey on a 14in 2021 MacBook Pro

Comment: The “ Deleting Photos Library.photoslibrary” step has me concerned. Have you good backups from before you started to troubleshoot?

Comment: @bmike Yes — although it's always a good reminder! For anyone trouble shooting something similar, you can download a full copy from https://privacy.apple.com/account : )

Comment: Did you try the solution steps separately or combined? What I would do is "disable iCloud", remove the Libray, remove any Photos preferences from ~/Library, reboot, re-enable iCloud, wait for a day, start Photos.

Comment: did you upload files to icloud? if you have taken from you phone, have you toggle a setting to upload files to icloud? please edit your questions and add these details

Comment: By "Running Recover Library", do you mean "Repair library" by holding down CMD + Option keys while launching the Photos app? Repair should recreate the thumbnails and fix whatever is causing this issue.

Comment: @MacEater Whoops, yes, that's what I meant. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

This is likely too late to help Adam, but I'll leave it here just in case it someone else runs into the same issue.

I had exactly the same problem. The fix was to go to the "Shared with You" section in the sidebar, and toggle "Filter" to "All Items". Seems like the filter was also affecting the Library, Favorites, and other sections.